# How to put the various into an array which is outside function scope

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Could anyone tell me how to put the "children" into the array ?

Thank you very much!

```
var deck = document.getElementsByClassName("deck")[0];
var moves = document.getElementsByClassName("moves")[0];
var count = 0;
var openedCard = [];

function handel(ev) {
  var target = ev.target;
  if (target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "li") {
    target.setAttribute("class", "card open show");
    count += 1;
    moves.innerHTML = count;
  }
  var children = target.children;
  openedCard.push(children)；
}

deck.addEventListener("click", handel, false)
```

Comment: is `children` itself an array?

Comment: @Jamiec, children just an various --var children = target.children;

Comment: The question itself is not clear to understand. 1. Do you want to add only tag name of all children elements or with content to array?   2. Do you want add all direct children elements or all nested children elements into an array? Lets have some clear understanding about your expectation, will help us to find answer you quicker.

Comment: @Antony SUTHAKAR J，1.I wanna add tag content to array 2. add all direct children elements, thank you!

Comment: Can you please add your HTML code here? or If you have any codepen/jsfiddle tryouts? would help us.

Comment: @Antony SUTHAKAR J  here it is:https://github.com/SylviaTsui/memoryGame/blob/master/folder/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is your function handel does not "see" the array openedCard, and the script tries to put an element into an undefined variable. If you use anonym function inside your listener, it might be work:

```
var deck = document.getElementsByClassName("deck")[0];
var moves = document.getElementsByClassName("moves")[0];
var count = 0;
var openedCard = [];

deck.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
    var target = ev.target;
    if (target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "li") {
        target.setAttribute("class", "card open show");
        count += 1;
        moves.innerHTML = count;
    }
    var children = target.children;
    openedCard.push(children)；
}, false)
```